# Изменение позиции карусели при открытии страницы

Tags: jquery

Использую плагин [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/).
Как можно придумать, чтобы при загрузке страницы карусель промоталась сразу до выбранной позиции, т.е. сначала отображалась, а, к примеру, начиная с 5 элемента и при этом можно было влево-вправо прокручивать.

**Добавлено.**

Нашел вот в примерах такое еще: [Carousel with external controls](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_controls.html). Что-то только пулю не могу привязать, просто к дом реди, чтобы пролистывалось после загрузки сразу.

Answer (score 1):

Лезть надо внутрь и смотреть.

В jquery есть метод

```
element.animate({'свойство':' конечное значение'});
```

привяжи этот метод к родитеслькому элементу содержимого карусели, т.е.: этот родительский элемент всего скорее относительно позиционирован, и в зависимости от ориентации карусели (горизонтально или вертикально) измени значение left:Xpx или top:Ypx;
Вызывать следует так:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   element.animate({'свойство':' конечное значение'});/* или вместо animate использовать css - тогда она без анимирования встанет куда надо. А вот куда она встанет надо вычислить, если ей нужно подвинуться на 5 елементов, то нужно вычислить сумму длин или высот этих 5-ти элементов`*/
});
```

Но лезть внутрь все равно притедться т.к. нужно еще вычислять размеры элементов карусели (картинки это или что-то иное), а там это ступудово вычисляется это все. Незнаю как у вас с jquery, но это очень легко самому сделать - имею ввиду написать такую карусель на jquery, и будет она такой какой вы захотите ее видеть.